# Get String/Byte between STX & ETX in Inputstream

Tags: java, android-studio, sockets, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm working on TCP socket but I realize it will only print the message ends with "\n".
The problem is the server will send the message ends with ETX (without "\n") hence I'm having trouble to print the String.
Is there any way to get data between the STX and ETX?

```
this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    rxMsg = input.readLine();
                 
                    Log.v("InputStream",rxMsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I've not tested your code, the cause lies on your `readLine` function call.
readLine does not finish its work until ETX is found.

Instead, try using [`read()` or `read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) instead of `readLine`. These functions receives arbitrary length of bytes (same or shorter than what the sender had sent) sometimes, then you may want to call `read` again for receiving the remaining data.